# Calling ImageMagick from C# (.net 6) on OSX: Getting "Library not loaded"

Tags: c#, macos, imagemagick

Im trying to use ImageMagick in a C# application on OSX.

My constraint is that I'm not allowed to install IM on the computer and I can't use homebrew or Magick.Net.

The application downloads ImageMagick-x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0.tar.gz from https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php and unpacks this to ~/test/

I'm using CliWrap:

```
var home = "~/test/ImageMagick-7.0.10/";

var result = await Cli
                .Wrap(home + "magick")
                .WithArguments(new[] { "-quiet", inputPath, outputPath }, true)
                .WhenOSX(builder => 
                    builder.WithEnvironmentVariables(env =>
                        env
                            .Set("MAGICK_HOME", home)
                            .Set("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH", home + "lib/"
                            .Set("PATH", home + "bin/"))
                    )
                .WithValidation(CommandResultValidation.None)
                .ExecuteBufferedAsync(cts.Token);
```

When running this I'm getting:

```
dyld[97894]: Library not loaded: /ImageMagick-7.0.10/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/niels/test/ImageMagick-7.0.10/bin/magick
  Reason: tried: '/ImageMagick-7.0.10/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.8.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.8.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.8.dylib' (no such file)
```

What can I do?

Comment: Would you mind sharing why you cannot use Magick.NET? And have you tried using DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH instead of DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: @dlemstra because I'm using this for some filetypes I've had issues with Magick.Net like cube, heic, jfif, jxl, mvg, flif conversions. Maybe there's a solution for those?